# How to start download from CGI in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, cgi

I have this CGI script, but how do I start a download in the browser?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-Type: text/plain"
echo

CUR=$(ls -t /var/www/html/certs/*$AUTHENTICATE_UID* | head -1)

if [ "$CUR" != "" ]; then

# start download in the browser

fi
```

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/003](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, you would emit the [Content-Disposition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) header:

```
echo "Content-Type: text/plain"

CUR=$(ls -t /var/www/html/certs/*$AUTHENTICATE_UID* | head -1)
if [ "$CUR" != "" ]; then
    echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourFile.txt"'
fi

echo  # End of headers.
```

Comment: With your script I get the download prompt, but the file I download is empty. Do I need to do something more?

Comment: Yes, you need to send the file content after the headers. The way to achieve this depends on where you fetch this content from, e.g. a simple `cat` will do the job if you want to send a static text file present on your server. Beware of the encoding, though.

Comment: Yes, `cat` also works with binary files. However, if you're sending a ZIP file, you probably don't want to serve it as `text/plain`. I'd suggest you use the `application/zip` content type instead.